# concatenate <dt> with <dd> in <table>

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to create page header and i need to concatenate dt and dd in one line 
This is my view code :

```
<div style="margin-left:100px">
    <hr />
    <dl class="horizontal">
        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Patient_Name)</dt> 
        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Patient_Name)</dd>
        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Patient_No)</dt> 
        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Patient_No)</dd> 
        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.SEX)</dt> 
        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.SEX)</dd>
        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.AGE)</dt>  
        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.AGE)</dd>
        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.order_number)</dt>  
        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.order_number)</dd>


    </dl>
</div>
```

The output now the title in one line and data in the second line :

Patient_Name

Sami Ali

Patient_No

345676

But I need the output like this :

Patient_Name  Sami Ali

Patient_No    345676

and so on, How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `css` like below. Update your `dt` and `dd` width as per your requirement.

There may apply some default `margin` to these elements so it may possible that if you make `widht` sum `100%` then it will display `dd` on next line.

```css
dt {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}

dd {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left:100px">
    <hr />
    <dl class="horizontal">
        <dt>Patient_Name</dt> 
        <dd>abc</dd>
        <dt>Patient_No</dt> 
        <dd>123</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```